# How to Get the Higher ID

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Can u Help me ..to create an oracle sql script .. pls. see outpout below

[image: ö]

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask], and show a [mcve].  You will get a better response that way.

Comment: pls. click 'enter image description here' for my desired output.. newbie here .. ty

Comment: Please do not post DATA in comments.  Nobody can read this mess.

Comment: Your question should  look something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678695/how-to-obtain-the-most-recent-row-per-type-and-perform-calculations-depending-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS greater_id,
       FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5
```

Comment: @mathguy Updated thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tim  !!   SUCCESS !!! :)